# Adding additional methods to JPA entity

Tags: java, jpa

I want to add method to my User entity that returns list of other entities, a list that is field in User entity but filtered. Problem is, when I add such method to entity class I get error

[class entities.WorksOnTask] uses a non-entity [class entities.User] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field user]

Why, how can I add method i User entity class that returns (filtered) list of WorksOnTask?

Or is there something else that I should do?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByUsername", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username = :username"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByPassword", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.password = :password"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByFirstName", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.firstName = :firstName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByLastName", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.lastName = :lastName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByAppPrivileges", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.appPrivileges = :appPrivileges"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByActivated", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.activated = :activated")})
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Username")
    private String username;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Password")
    private String password;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "FirstName")
    private String firstName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "LastName")
    private String lastName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "AppPrivileges")
    private int appPrivileges;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Activated")
    private boolean activated;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<WorksOnProject> worksOnProjectList;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<WorksOnTask> worksOnTaskList;
public List<WorksOnTask> getWorksOnTaskList(){
    return worksOnTaskList;
}

public void setWorksOnTaskList(List<WorksOnTask> worksOnTaskList) {
    this.worksOnTaskList = worksOnTaskList;
}
public List<WorksOnTask> findWorksOnTaskListNonRemoved(){
    return new  ArrayList(worksOnTaskList).stream().filter((w)->!w.getRemoved()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Stack trace shows error for entity task, but everything is same as in User.

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException     at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)     at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at
com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:303)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start
method  at
com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:875)
    at
com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(LauncherImpl.java:157)
    at
com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$53/200006406.run(Unknown
Source)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: Exception
[EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for
persistence archives with ClassLoader:
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@55f96302 Internal Exception:
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018]
(Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd):
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [DBPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence
Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd):
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException Exception
Description: [class entities.Project] uses a non-entity [class
entities.Task] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field
iDRootTask].    at
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPersistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:127)
    at
org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:107)
    at
org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:177)
    at
javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at
javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at pg.jpa.JpaAccessManager.<init>(JpaAccessManager.java:24)     at
pg.Login.start(Login.java:49)   at
com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:821)
    at
com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$56/574011920.run(Unknown
Source)     at
com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
    at
com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$50/1768305536.run(Unknown
Source)     at
com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
    at
com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$52/1148099840.run(Unknown
Source)     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at
com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at
com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$51/1146743572.run(Unknown
Source)     at
com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  at
com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$45(GtkApplication.java:126)
    at
com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$$Lambda$42/379110473.run(Unknown
Source)     ... 1 more Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [DBPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence
Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd):
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException Exception
Description: [class entities.Project] uses a non-entity [class
entities.Task] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field
iDRootTask].    at
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1954)
    at
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1945)
    at
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.callPredeploy(JPAInitializer.java:98)
    at
org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:96)
    ... 19 more Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse
Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd):
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [DBPU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence
Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd):
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException Exception
Description: [class pentities.Project] uses a non-entity [class
entities.Task] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field
iDRootTask].    at
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:230)
    ... 23 more Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse
Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd):
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException Exception
Description: [class entities.Project] uses a non-entity [class
entities.Task] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field
iDRootTask].    at
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.nonEntityTargetInRelationship(ValidationException.java:1378)
    at
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.RelationshipAccessor.getReferenceDescriptor(RelationshipAccessor.java:553)
    at
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ObjectAccessor.processForeignKeyRelationship(ObjectAccessor.java:659)
    at
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ObjectAccessor.processOwningMappingKeys(ObjectAccessor.java:733)
    at
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ManyToOneAccessor.process(ManyToOneAccessor.java:123)
    at
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processOwningRelationshipAccessors(MetadataProject.java:1580)
    at
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processStage3(MetadataProject.java:1833)
    at
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:580)
    at
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:585)
    at
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1869)
    ... 21 more Exception running application pg.Login
```

Comment: Are you annotating methods (getters) instead of fields?

Comment: No.Especially not this method, it's just a convenience method.

Comment: Can you post the code of `User` entity, together with the method that causes the problem? Also, a full stack trace would be nice.

Comment: Wop is actually WorksOnTask, but I though it's unnecessary to post original and even better/simpler. I hope this part of code will be enough.

Comment: I'll have to switch branch and return to commit where there was that problem. Just a sec

Comment: Strange that you get this exception just after adding that method, there seems to be no relation between the two. Can you try implementing the method old style, without Java 8 features? Also, use getter instead of direct field access for `worksOnTaskList`.

Comment: Well, it don't really need to. I left this question just for curiosity. I have solved it by putting query inside that method that gets me data I want. Thank you anyway. Hvala ;)

Comment: I know you got it resolved, I was just curious about what caused the issue in the first place. And nema na čemu :)

Comment: Oh, If that's the case I'll try what you want.

Comment: I think I have found what's the problem. Take a look at my answer. Strange really.

Comment: Strange it is, I wonder if there is already a bug filed against this, cause it looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is solved in EclipseLink 2.6.0 https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=429992

Answer (score 4):

I did find kind of answer to this question. Problem is that, it seems that I can't access mapped field of entity class inside that method. But I have used query to get information that I want.

So I have no problem anymore. But still question is there, looking for answer.

EDIT:
OK, it seems that using lambda expressions inside method that belongs to entity class creates problems.

for example, this doesn't work:

```
public List<WorksOnTask> getWorksOnTaskListNonRemoved() {
    ArrayList<WorksOnTask> wots =  new ArrayList<>(worksOnTaskList);
    wots.removeIf((w)->w.getRemoved());
    return wots;
}
```

But this does (or at least application starts without error):

```
public List<WorksOnTask> getWorksOnTaskListNonRemoved() {
    ArrayList<WorksOnTask> wots =  new ArrayList<>(worksOnTaskList);
    wots.removeIf(new Predicate<WorksOnTask>(){

        @Override
        public boolean test(WorksOnTask t) {
            return t.getRemoved();
        }

    });

    return wots;
}
```

This is not the only case where Java 8 streams and lambdas don't work together very well.
Streams don't work with entity's IndirectLists. So I when I use them together, I need to write something like this:

```
new ArrayList<>(user.getWorksOnTaskList()).stream().....
```

instead of this:

```
user.getWorksOnTaskList().stream()......
```

It's too bad, I like streams more than I like JPA.